# How to cut strips and keep the keyframes in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes

I have two strips, A and B, which I want to smoothly switch between from time to time, so I keyframed the opacity on both strips, like this:

[image: Strips with keyframes]

This is what that looks like in the Graph Editor:

[image: Keyframes in graph editor]

But after reviewing the footage I want to keep the transitions (ie. the keyframes) but remove some footage in the middle. So I select both of them and press K to cut:

[image: Strips after cut]

As you can see, the strips on the right retain the keyframe information but the original (left) strips have lost the keyframes. Let's assume I have a lot of them and it would be a pain to put them back.

Is there a way of cutting a strip (or multiple strips) and have the keyframes retained on both sides of the cut?

I tried selecting all in the graph editor window prior to doing the cut, doing the cut, and then pasting, but pasting is grayed out after the cut.

---

Blender 3.1.0.

---

**NOTE:** It seems to work how I would expect using Blender 2.93.0 Beta, and in Blender 3.0.0. So, perhaps this is just a candidate for a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T96699).

[image]

Comment: The Blender developers [have confirmed this is a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T96699) and have triaged it as high priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug. It has been fixed here:
https://developer.blender.org/rBe74420124f3a429ad8a1492e56a7e1561d86d6f7